# rationale behind lock inside lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am reviewing an example code in a book and came across the following code(simplified).
In the code, when `Subscribe(T subscriber)` is called, the thread enters into a lock section.
and then, when code inside the lock calls `AddToSubscribers(T subscriber)` method, the method has another lock. why is this second lock necessary?

```
public abstract class SubscriptionManager<T> where T : class 
{
   private static List<T> subscribers;
   private static void AddToSubscribers(T subscriber)
   {
      lock (typeof(SubscriptionManager<T>))
      {
         if (subscribers.Contains(subscriber))
            return;
         subscribers.Add(subscriber);
      }
   }

   public void Subscribe(T subscriber)
   {
      lock (typeof(SubscriptionManager<T>))
      {
         AddToSubscribers(subscriber);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that context, it isn't; however, since locks are re-entrant that can be useful to ensure that any other caller of `AddToSubscribers` observes the lock. Actually, for that reason I'd say "remove it from `Subscribe` and just let `AddToSubscribers` do the locking".

However! A lock on a `Type` is pretty dangerous. A field would be safer:

```
// assuming static is correct
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
```

and `lock(syncLock)`. Depending on when `subscribers` is assigned, you might also get away with `lock(subscribers)` (and no extra field).

I should also note that having an **instance** method add to **static** state is pretty.... unusual; IMO `Subscribe` should be a `static` method, since it has nothing to do with the current instance.

Comment: actually, this example comes out from a WCF book, and the SubscriptionManager<T> class is the base class for WCF service classes. hence the instance methods are required. I also read from MSDN that lock on a Type is dangerous as you stated, does the fact that the context is WCF make any difference?

Comment: @Marc "private static readonly object syncLock = new object(); " - this gives a single global lock for all SubscriptionManager<T>; whereas I believe the original code has one lock per constructed type (i.e. one for each distinct "T").

Comment: @Joe no, that is incorrect; static fields in a generic type are per-generic-type-parameter-permutation, so per-`T` in this case.

Comment: @Marc you're right, I'm wrong, and have learned something today, +1

Answer (score 3):

In the code you posted, it isn't necessary. But then again, the code you posted is incomplete - for example the subscribers list is never initialized.

Locking on typeof(SubscriptionManager) is probably not a good idea either - locking on the `subscribers` field would be better - but would require the subscribers field to be initialized, e.g.

```
private static List<T> subscribers = new List<T>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should read near that sample and see what book talks about.

For that particular case - no, second lock is unnecessary.

Note: The sample is dangerous since it locks on public object (type). Normally one locks on special private object so external code is not able to mistakenly introduce deadlocks by mistakenly locking on the same object.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a situation once where I had to use nested Lock.

My case was, the function of the second lock maybe called from elsewhere, since it was a static function. However, for your case it won't be necessary since each data member belongs to an Instance and not static..